# Android paddingBottom not working without paddingTop

Tags: android, layout, scrollview, padding

I am currently using a layout that contains a RelativeLayout inside a ScrollView.

I want the RelativeLayout to be contained 5dp away from the bottom of the ScrollView so it does not overlap the background I have behind it, to achieve this I was using this XML:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/backgroundView1"
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/innerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This worked perfectly, however I no longer need the padding at the top. When removing the paddingTop line, the paddingBottom no longer functions. Even if I set the paddingBottom to 100dp it shows no effect on my layout.

I tried paddingTop="0dp" and that did not fix the issue either, it seems paddingBottom will only work when paddingTop is above 0.

Anyone got any ideas as to why paddingBottom does not work without paddingTop?

Comment: I tried you code and it works when the top padding is zero. I used a relative layout as the parent layout.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote xml property **android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"** so your **ScrollView** will always it will be aligned **bottom**.

Remove **android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"** and try again.

Answer (score 0):

use this kind of layout for scrollview and change according to your need..dont use relative layout inside scrollview.
Here you can set any type height in image and still you will see padding at bottom without any paddingtop

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/backgroundView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#cccccc"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/innerLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="700dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/image2" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
```

or

```
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
```

Answer (score -1):

**This is for having (5 dp) space on top and bottom**

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/backgroundView1"
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/innerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**This is for having (5 dp) space on top, bottom, left, and right**

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/backgroundView1"
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/innerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp">
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```